# Field of an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was doing some exercises from a book and the following question arose: suppose we have a linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, could it have a complex number as its eigenvalue? That is, necessarily the field to which the eigenvalue belongs must be $\mathbb{R}?$ At first it seemed logical to me to assume that the eigenvalue was limited by $\mathbb{R}$, but the conceptual doubt arose and I couldn't find a way to see if that made sense.

---

I thought the following: $T(v) = \lambda\,v$. Then $\lambda\,v$ must belong to $\mathbb{R}^3$ (and $v$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}^3$), then $\lambda$ in particular must belong to $\mathbb{R}$. Is that approach correct?

(Note: I invented the example to be able to clarify a specific doubt, in case something is not understood, let me know.)

Comment: In general eigenvalues are solutions to characteristic polynomial, which has complex roots. There are special transformations that guarantees real e.values.

Comment: I suppose you can always restrict your conplex solutions to real e.values. similarly, if you restrict yourself to rational vectors, you then always obtain rational e.values, and restrict your solutions similarly. For irrational numbers you need to be careful since irrational divided by irrational can be rational.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a bit hand-wavey.

When it comes to eigenvalues of linear transformations (and also characteristic solutions of differential and difference equations, poles of Laplace transforms, and many other seemingly unrelated contexts) the real part relates to exponential growth, and the imaginary part relates to oscillations. (Really, the absolute value relates to exponential growth and the complex argument relates to oscillations, which come to think of it, are really exponential growths as well.)

To illustrate: Take the linear transformation that is a $90^\circ$ rotation about the $z$ axis. It has three eigenvalues. The only real eigenvalue is $1$ with the eigenvector $[0,0,1]$, which as you repeatedly apply the transformation grows exponentially with factor $1$ (which is to say, is entirely unchanged).

Then you have two eigenvalues of $\pm i$. These two eigenvalues correspond to the $90^\circ$ rotation that we started with (in the same way that multiplication by $\pm i$ rotates the complex plane by $90^\circ$). Indeed, any rotation matrix has the corresponding points on the complex unit circle as eigenvalues.

So if you have a linear transformation of a real vector space where things "just grow and squish" and "do not rotate", then all eigenvalues are going to be real. If there is rotation involved, then there will be non-real eigenvalues. (Note that even matrices that obviously have only real eigenvalues, such as $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ will seemingly "rotate" a vector like $[1, 1]$ in addition to stretching it, so what I mean by "rotation" in this context is more complicated than it may seem at first glance. I said it would be hand-wavey.)

Comment: I think the question was more focused on how restricting the field of our transformation spaces affects possible e.values.

Comment: @DavidRaveh You may be right. Oh well.